# Sqlalchemy, zope transactions and .user attribute

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, zope, zodb

Transaction manager has [setUser](http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=setuser#transaction.ITransaction.setUser) method and under .[user](http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=setuser#transaction.ITransaction.user) attr description we have

> Storages record the user value, as meta-data, when a transaction commits.

Is it related only to ZoDB (and method setUser defined only to implement ITransaction interface)? Or I can achieve this information when using mysql with sqlalchemy and should set unique user attr to good purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is currently only used by the ZODB; the SQLAlchemy integration ignores that information.

You could use it still but you'd have to extend the `zope.sqlalchemy` session data manager to do something with that information. You could add additional rows to your database based on the note and user, perhaps.